# python can't specific xpath for <a> tag

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

please look at this image from firebug

[image]

i want to get the test inside the `<a>` tag. i used this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="item paid-featured-item"]/div[@class="listing-item"]')
    cars = []
    for site in sites:
        car = CarItem()
        car['ATitle']=xpath('.//div[@class="block item-title"]/h3/span[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract()
        cars.append(car)
    return cars
```

I think i have used the correct xpath. but it seems no because i got empty result.

any help?

Comment: Don't know if it's a typo or not but you should have something like `car['ATitle'] = site.xpath(...`, not `car['ATitle']=xpath(...`

Comment: @pault. i didn't know that. is it not correct to use spaces?

Comment: @pault. however i just tried to use space, still no result

Comment: @pault. write the answer please to accept it. you solve my problem

Comment: next time in firebug better right click and choose 'Copy Html' taking a picture may not be the best idea...

Comment: I wasnt referring to the use of spaces, but the use of `site.xpath()` instead of simply `xpath()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following OP's comment:

this is probably what you aimed for:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="item paid-featured-item"]/div[@class="listing-item"]')
    cars = []
    for site in sites:
        car = CarItem()
        car['ATitle']=site.xpath('.//div[@class="block item-title"]/h3/span[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract()
        cars.append(car)
    return cars
```

Alternatively, I see you're using a recent Scrapy version, so you may want to try CSS selectors that usually make selector expression easier to read and maintain.

In your case, you could use something like

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.css('div.paid-featured-item div.listing-item')
    cars = []
    for site in sites:
        car = CarItem()
        car['ATitle'] = site.css('div.item-title h3 span.title a::text').extract()
        cars.append(car)
    return cars
```

Note that the `a::text` syntax is a Scrapy extension to CSS selectors